# how to show min and max value in linechart using mpchart in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart, linechart

I want to show the Min and Max value on the line chart i am using the library MPChart Android library.

I want to show min max as like this.

### [image]

My Code for the Line chart

```
  val lineDataSet = LineDataSet(values, "")
            lineDataSet.lineWidth = 2f
            lineDataSet.setDrawValues(true)
            lineDataSet.setDrawFilled(true)
//            lineDataSet.fillAlpha = 85
            lineDataSet.setDrawCircles(false)
//            lineDataSet.setCircleColor(Color.BLACK)
            lineDataSet.color = resources.getColor(R.color.green)
//            lineDataSet.fillColor = resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
            lineDataSet.highLightColor = resources.getColor(R.color.coral);

            val elevationMarker = ChartMarkerView2(activity)
            binding!!.chart.markerView = elevationMarker
            lineDataSet.setDrawHighlightIndicators(true)
            lineDataSet.setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(false)
            lineDataSet.setDrawCircleHole(true)
            lineDataSet.circleHoleRadius = 5f
            lineDataSet.setCircleColor(
                resources.getColor(R.color.green)
            )


            val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.fade_graph_bg)
            lineDataSet.fillDrawable = drawable
            lineDataSet.axisDependency = YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT
//            lineDataSet.cubicIntensity = 0f
//            lineDataSet.mode = LineDataSet.Mode.HORIZONTAL_BEZIER;


            val dataSets = ArrayList<ILineDataSet>()
            dataSets.add(lineDataSet) // add the datasets

            // create a data object with the datasets
            val data = LineData(dataSets)
//            data.setDrawValues(false)
            // set data
            binding!!.chart.data = data
//            binding!!.chart.animateX(100)
            binding!!.chart.invalidate()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get Max- Min your Dataset and in ValueFormatter Modify your value like this :

```
 val numArr1 = intArrayOf(10000, 10100, 12200,12700, 9036, 11200, 10200)
 val max = numArr1.maxOrNull() ?: 0
 val min = numArr1.minOrNull() ?: 0
 valueFormatter = object : ValueFormatter() {
    override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
    if (value == min.toFloat() || value == max.toFloat())
       { 
          return "$value $" 
       }
         return ""
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet to set minimum and maximum value in Linechart using MPAndroidChart library.

```
val chartEntities: ArrayList<Entry> = ArrayList()
val values = Array(5) {0f}
values[0] = 5f
values[1] = 2.2f
values[2] = 7.2f
values[3] = 9.5f
values[4] = 4.5f
values[5] = 6.4f

var i = 0
for (entry in values) {
    var value = values[i]
    chartEntities.add(Entry(i.toFloat(), value))
    i++
}

val lineDataSet = LineDataSet(chartEntities, "")

val max = values.maxOrNull() ?: 0
val min = values.minOrNull() ?: 0
val valueFormatter = object : ValueFormatter() {
    override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
        if (value == min.toFloat() || value == max.toFloat())
        {
            return "$value"
        }
        return ""
    }
}

lineDataSet.valueFormatter = valueFormatter
lineDataSet.setDrawValues(true)
```

With this sample snippet you can set minimum and maximum values in linechart using MPAndroidChart.

1. Create float array of items to display in the line chart
2. find out minimum and maximum values from the arraylist.
3. create ValueFormatter and set values there.
4. set valueFormatter property to lineDataSet
5. set setDrawValues(true) in lineDataSet

Hope this helps. Happy coding.